# Dual monitors randomly don't work on Acer Aspire 6930

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, hdmi, acer-aspire

I've been using a TV as a second monitor with my Aspire using its HDMI port (the TV supports DVI, so I'm just using a converter). However, it's been flaky and the external display would stop working after a reboot or if the computer went to sleep.

I tried updating the drivers (Mobile Intel 4 Series Express), and now I can't get the HDMI display to work at all. It seems like Vista isn't detecting the TV when the cable is plugged in (no sound or anything). Under the Display Settings, it visually shows displays 1 and 2 at all times (with or without the TV attached) and selecting `Extend the desktop onto this monitor` just reverts back after you hit Apply (again, with or without the TV attached). I also looked into the Device Manager, and there it also doesn't show any new monitors.

Also, the `Fn+F5` key combination which is supposed to cycle between display 1, 2, and both, doesn't do anything (although it was working when the display on

Answer (score 1):

Mine just did this, and a guy at a computer shop i work at had me unplug the laptop, shut it down pull the battery out and then hit the power button a few times (3 or 4) then put the battery back in power it back up plug in your power cord then try connecting the HDMI to the TV, and it worked on my laptop Acer Aspire 6930.